# Error when pushing a stringstream to a priority queue<stringstream>

Tags: c++, priority-queue

```
std::stringstream makeString(std::string name, std::string number) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string load;
    if(number.size() == 1) {
        ss << "0" << number << " - " << name << std::endl;
    } else {
        ss << number << " - " << name << std::endl;
    }
    return ss;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    // Write your code here
    std::string inputs;
    std::string priority;
    std::priority_queue<std::stringstream> pqueue;

    while(1 == 1) {

        input("What do you want to do? ", inputs);
        if (inputs == "add") {
            input("Name: ", inputs);
            input("Priority: ", priority);
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << makeString(inputs, priority).str();
            std::cout << ss.str();
            pqueue.push(ss);
        } else if (inputs == "take") {
            std::stringstream holder;
            holder << pqueue.top().str();
            pqueue.pop();
            std::cout << holder.str() << std::endl;
        } else if (inputs == "end") {
            return 0;
        } else {
            std::cout << inputs << " isn't a valid operation" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It should be able to push the stringstream to the priority queue, but it tells me that it's a "call to deleted constructor of 'std::basic_stringstream'"

How do I fix this? Can I not use stringstreams in a priority queue?

Comment: Streams can't be copied. Therefore it can't be copied into the queue. Why do you want a queue of streams, instead of a queue of strings?

Comment: Streams are non-copyable. You can still move your streams: `pqueue.push(std::move(ss));`, or `pqueue.push(std::stringstream("xxx"));`, or you can reconsider your design.

Comment: Also, there's no built-in ordering for streams, how is one stream smaller or larger than another stream? How would they be prioritized?

Comment: *Can I not use stringstreams in a priority queue?* -- This is a classic [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `**pqueue.push(ss);**` -- Do not use `*` to highlight lines of code.  It can be confused with the pointer or derefencing operator.  If anything, do this: `pqueue.push(ss); // <-- This gives an error`.  Not only does that code compile, it is descriptive enough and does not confuse fake `*` characters with actual pointer and dereferencing.

Comment: Since the only code that uses the string stream always calls `str()`, it certainly looks like the queue should be a queue of `std::string`, and that `makeString` (as its name implies) should return `std::string`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in the function `makeString`, rather than write the same code twice, I'd write `if (number.size() == 1) ss << "0"; ss << number << " - " << name << std::endl;`. That way if you later have to change what the generated text looks like you don't have to make the same change in two different places.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my understanding is that using strings won't let me output whitelines?

Comment: I assume what you call a "whiteline" is simply an empty string? An empty string is just a default-constructed `std::string`, there's nothing special with it. Writing an empty string to a stream is perfectly fine, it will simply not write anything.